# How to get Reward Points data in Custom API?

Tags: magento2, cart, reward-points

In Magento 2.4, I want to get the Reward-points which going to earn for particular order from cart page into custom API. How to get Reward Points data in Custom API?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

In the `etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/rewards/points/:customerId" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\RewardPointsInterface" method="getPoints"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customerId%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
</routes>
```

In the Vendor/Module/Api/RewardPointsInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface RewardPointsInterface
{
    /**
     * Get customer reward points
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPoints($customerId);
}
```

In the Vendor/Module/Model/RewardPoints.php:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Api\RewardPointsInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Reward\Model\ResourceModel\Reward\History\CollectionFactory;

class RewardPoints implements RewardPointsInterface
{
    private $customerFactory;
    private $rewardHistoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        CollectionFactory $rewardHistoryCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->rewardHistoryCollectionFactory = $rewardHistoryCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer reward points
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPoints($customerId)
    {
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
        
        $rewardPoints = $this->rewardHistoryCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
            ->getFirstItem();
        
        $pointsBalance = $rewardPoints->getPointsBalance();
        
        return $pointsBalance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rana, But the points will be added after invoice generation and also this `getFirstItem` will give last received point. But I need the points for particular order- before placing order, in cart page.

Comment: Then you need to specify the specific order ID

Comment: But before placing order, how you will get reward points data??

Comment: Something like this: You would earn 4 Reward points from this order.

Comment: If there was already rewards points then it will be possilble to get the rewards points before order placed.